# Thymeleaf only shows content of index.html

Tags: spring, redirect, thymeleaf

It is my first time working with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf.
I set up the project with the initializer from https://start.spring.io/.

The idea is to directly go to the "welcome" page when hitting the endpoint "/".
The issue is that i can not go to another page except the "index.html".                                                       Furthermote when hitting "/application" I get **"This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback."**

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "redirect:/welcome";
    }

    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public String application() {
        return "welcome";
    }
}

@Controller
public class ApplicationController {

    @GetMapping("application")
    public String showStartPage(){
        return "application";
    }
}



welcome.html
<html>
    <h3>Welcome Page!</h3>
</html>

application.html
<html>
    <h3>Application Page!</h3>
</html>

apllication.properties
logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0-M2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-openai</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-openai</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

My files are in /resources/templates

I tried to use different maven dependencies and also changed the directory of the .html files.
Furthermore used @PostMapping.
Also, deactivated **CSRF protection** in "welcome.html"

Comment: I found the solution.
Since i changed my project structure in "springbootapp" to /controller /entities /services, i had to set the scan for the Spring Beans correctly.
`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com/example/springbootapp")
{}
`